# Show all c++ #include dependecies

Tags: c++, include

Is there a way to list all files included in a generic .cpp file?
I need a list (flat) or a hierarchical tree that show all the included files from a .cpp file?
Does the compilator has some flag to show them? or using another tool? how can i achieve taht?

Comment: You should probably specify your compiler/platform but `g++` has the `-H` option.

Comment: At least g++ has the `-M<x>` options group to support GNU make dependency lists.

Comment: Further to the comment by πάντα ῥεῖ you might want to clarify the rationale for this.  If it's for use as target dependencies in a `makefile` you should probably state that and add the `makefile` tag.  You might also want to read [this](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/).